# What are some advantages to the different programming languages?

Tags: c#, javascript, c++, visual-c++, visual-c#-express-2010

I have always had an interest in coding, and a while back a started to learn C#. Since I only do this as a hobby, i have been learning it very slowly and don't know too much yet, but when I started to read about C++ and how it runs closer to the OS, I started to wonder if I should start learning C++ instead. I know html and JavaScript pretty well and to me C# seemed to be somewhat similar to js, so it wasn't to hard. I just downloaded C++ Express and noticed it is in a very different style than what I'm used to. I'm wondering if I should stick with c# or try c++ (especially if I want to start playing with Arduino sometime in the future). What are some advantages/ disadvantages to both?

Comment: If you have any interest in embedded devices, you definitely should learn some C and C++.  Don't mess with the Visual C++ Express flavor of C++ for .NET (C++/CLI) though until you have a good understanding of standard C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a person who has done all of these languages professionally, I would say that C# is probably the easiest to learn while still being very powerful.  There is a lot of help for the .NET platform both from the libraries standpoint and from the community as well.  Unless you really want to get down and dirty with a language, stick with C#.

The bigger answer, however, is "it depends".  If you are looking to learn a language for the sake of learning one, C# is the way to go.  However, if you are thinking about possibly using this new skill in a job setting, look for what type of job you want and decide from there.  If you are looking to build applications for yourself and your friends, stick with C#.  You can build a Winforms app in about five minutes and you can scale to larger and more professional apps easily from there.  C++ will be much more difficult to do the same with.

Answer (score 1):

Coming from Javascript, I would probably recommend staying with C# if you don't want to get down and dirty with details. It will take care of memory management and several other low-level concerns that C++ makes you deal with manually, so it's a little less of a shock to go from an interpreted scripting language like Javascript or Python or Ruby to C#. It's kinda half-way between them and C++.

That said, if you want to learn more of how programming languages and computers in general work, go for C++. It's more complicated than C#, but learning C++ very well makes any language you learn after that easy. Plus with C++, there's virtually no limit to what you can do (C# imposes a few limits), and you pretty much have the entire computer with *all* its speed and resources at your disposal.

*That said*, C++ usually takes longer to do the same thing in. For instance, creating a Windows application with a GUI and everything would take a considerable amount of time in C++, but in C# it's trivial. It's a tradeoff you have to deal with, but like I said, if you learn C++ first, C# is cake. The converse is not necessarily true though.

If you want to work with Arduino, go for C++ (never worked with Arduino but the code snippets looked like C so..). C++ is very similar to C, and most C will compile as C++ with very little modification.

Comment: I agree with most of this, but not all of it. C++ does not make you deal with memory management manually; it's supported RAII from the beginning, and boost::shared_ptr has got to be *at least* 12 years old now! Perhaps you're thinking of C, which is very different than C++...

Comment: Nope, I'm thinking of plain C++. boost::shared_ptr is just a library which does it for you, so C++ made _someone_ do the manual memory management, whereas in C# it's part of the language. And I don't think RAII does what you think it does.

Comment: shared_ptr was just recently added to C++, but std::auto_ptr has always been part of C++ (the C++ language, by definition, includes the standard libraries; this is different than C#). So, C++ never *made* anyone do manual memory management. After more than a decade working in C++, it just always astonishes me how many people write C code in C++...

Comment: By "part of the language" I mean something that's built in, not part of any library. GC is built in to most interpreted languages, not as a library but as part of the core language.